# How can I deploy previous version of node server without manually undo sequelize migration

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, database-migration

I'm using node + postgres + sequlize + aws ec2 + rds

I deployed version to production that contains some sequelize migration scripts.
Now I want to revert and deploy the prev version to production.

**How should I do it?**

I can't just deploy the previous version because I need to undo the migrations first.

Is my only solution is to ssh the machine -> undo the migrations -> deploy the prev version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the approach, first deploy the previous version and the undo the migration.

In case you don't need 100% availability, just stop everything, do the two processes and start them up again.

In case you need 100% availability, always make DB changes backward compatible, so you can revert the app. After the application code is reverted, revert the migration.